# GLFW fails to create a window due to memory issues, likely caused by poor use of pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, memory, glfw

I've been using Windows 10's code::blocks IDE to attempt to create the foundations of a graphics engine. Essentially I have run into problems with memory when trying to allow for future ability to create multiple windows if necessary.

To do this, I created a class 'windowClass' within a file called window.cpp. Here is the declaration:

```
class windowClass {
public:
    int Width, Height;
    GLFWwindow* mainWindow;
    bool fullscreen;  };
```

declaring an instance of the class called 'GameWindow':

```
windowClass GameWindow;
```

You can see that there are public values of Width, Height and a GLFW window called 'mainWindow'. Later in this 'window.cpp' file, I wanted to create a function that would allow me to define this GLFW window.

Function declaration:

```
void createWindow(windowClass* window)
```

and then window definition within the function:

```
window->mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(860, 640, "gameWindow", NULL, NULL);
window->fullscreen = false;
window->Width = 860;
window->Height = 640;
```

Here, my goal was to use a pointer to a WindowClass so that any changes made within the function would be permanent for the rest of the program. Finally, before attempting to run the program, I called the function within 'main.cpp'

```
class windowClass *windowPointer = &GameWindow;
createWindow(windowPointer);
```

Again, the goal here was to make sure that any changes made to the classes within the createWindow function were passed to the TRUE GameWindow, not just an instance of it.

Despite these intentions, when I'm debugging, and once all of the changes to 'GameWindow' has been stepped through, 'GameWindow's various variables end up with the following values in the 'watch' window:

- mainWindow: 0x35c
- Width: 640
- Height: 40776776
- fullscreen: false

I would like to point out that 'Width' was passed what 'Height' was meant to recieve, and that mainWindow received a value of 0x35c, while, in working programs, GLFW windows get a value of something like: 0x8133b0

All of these errors in memory allocation result in a SIGSEGV fault when trying to  run this while loop:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(GameWindow.mainWindow)) {
    glfwSwapBuffers(GameWindow.mainWindow);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

**Here's my question:** Is there something wrong with the pointers and memory management I'm writing, is my  C++ code terrible, or am  I taking a horrible approach to this entire problem?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that demonstrates your problem? We can't really tell what's wrong without seeing where, for example, you are defining `GameWindow`. Is it a global variable or a local variable that is going out of scope?

Comment: Yeah no problem, I'll edit the question so it's more clear

Comment: Actually, @Sam the second excerpt of code I added, the 'windowClass GameWindow;' was where I am defining 'GameWindow'. It was declared in window.cpp, and linked to main.cpp using a header called window.h, where it is linked with 'extern windowClass GameWindow'. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Sam, I've resolved the problem: the glfwCreateWindow function within the GLFW library does not support creating a window within a class that contains other variables. Once I removed the Width, Height, and fullscreen variables from the 'WindowClass', everything was sovled. Thanks for checking in :)

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't sound right at all. I think you've still got a bug there and removing those variables has just masked it!

Comment: I'm not really sure what to say; after playing around some more, I was able to change those variables in a **different** function... Do you still think that I have a bug? I do respect your opinion on this, as you ar far more experienced than I am. It just seems to me that either that GLFW is bugged, or I'm not using it the way it was meant to be used... What do you think?

Comment: @Sam? Just trying to make sure you see the last comment :)

Comment: Yep sorry I see it, I was asleep (it was night time in Australia ;). I do think there's something fishy. glfwCreateWindow most definitely doesn't care where you put its return value; you can put it in a class, in a global variable, in a class with other members etc.

Comment: I agree. Fishiness is written all over my code. But, I'm ok with it since the workaround works fine for me. I appreciate the thought you put in to helping me out though. If you're OK with letting it rest unsolved, so am I :)

Comment: No problem, ultimately if you're happy and have a solution that's all that matters!

Comment: *"the glfwCreateWindow function within the GLFW library does not support creating a window within a class that contains other variables"* - This is impossible. `glfwCreateWindow` can not know and does not care if the pointer is part of a class or not. There is definitely some other mistake in the code. Post a complete reproducible example.